# Maximum likelihood estimator for power law with negative exponent

Tags: probability-distributions, power-series, estimation-theory

### Background

I have data that roughly follows a power law with a negative exponent (up to a point; also, the parameters of the "fit" were just guesstimated by eye as a demonstration):

[image]

Now I tried using the histogram to fit a power law in the shape of

$$f(x) = k \cdot x^a,$$

but I quickly realized that this strongly depends not only on the bin size, but also on whether or not I normalize the histogram (to drop $k$ in the process). So I already inquired about how to approach this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/563731/280304), where I was (I guess unsurprisingly) told that it's not a good idea to fit a histogram at all, and to use maximum likelihood estimators (MLEs) instead.

### Question

Now I've started to read up about MLEs, and I'm starting to understand what they are all about, but mind you, I'm *not* a mathematician. First, I tried to derive the MLEs on my own, but ultimately got stuck. If

$$f(x_i; k, a) = k \cdot x_i^a,$$

then I think

$$L(x_i; k, a) = k^n \cdot \left(\prod_i^n x_i\right)^a,$$

which means

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial k} = n \cdot k^{n-1} \cdot \left(\prod_i^n x_i\right)^a, \hspace{1cm} \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = k^n \cdot \left(\prod_i^n x_i\right)^a \cdot \sum_i^n \ln{x_i}.$$

When I set them equal to zero, I can solve for $k$:

$$k = \frac{n}{\sum_i^n \ln{x_i}},$$

but that's as far as I got, and I'm not even sure if that's correct. I didn't manage to sove for $a$, but then I came across [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/66731), which is very related to my question, but unfortunately, I didn't really undestand the answers. I did look into the [referenced paper by Clauset et al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062) though. But it seems that their MLEs are not concerned with my problem:

> We assume in these calculations that α > 1, since distributions with α ≤ 1 are
> not normalizable and hence cannot occur in nature. It is possible for a probability
> distribution to go as x−α with α ≤ 1 if the range of x is bounded above by some cutoff,
> but different maximum likelihood estimators are needed to fit such a distribution.

Then I found [this paper by White et al.](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/07-1288.1), which I think is concerned with my problem, but it's all going over my head at the moment.

So in conclusion, I'm looking for MLEs for $k$ and $a$, though I guess I would also need to address the cutoff for small $x$ somehow.

Comment: This question should rather be asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Notice that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^{-a}\, dx = +\infty,$ so this cannot be a probability density function no matter what constant you multiply it by. The Pareto distribution is $\displaystyle \text{constant} \times x^{-a} \text{ for } x>x_0$ and $x_0>0$ is one of the parameters determining the distribution. The constant by which this must be multiplied to get a probability density is determined by $a$ and $x_0.$ The likelihood function is a function of the parameters $a$ and $x_0$ with the data $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ fixed. The MLE of $x_0$ should not be$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$sought by finding a point where the derivative of the likelihood function is $0$ (nor should any extremum be sought by that method until one understands enough to see that that is appropriate). Rather, the set of possible values of $x_0$ is the interval $(0,\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}].$ The likelihood increases as $x_0$ increases within that interval, so the MLE of $x_0$ is that minimum, the right endpoint of the interval. Recall from calculus that when the largest value of a function is sought within a closed bounded interval, it may be at an endpoint of$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$the interval, and in that case it's not generally at a point where the derivative is zero. And that is what happens with $x_0.$ One can then seek an MLE of $a$ or of the normalizing constant but not of both separately, since the value of either, once given $x_0,$ completely determines the value of the other.

Comment: $$ \int_{x_0}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^a} = \frac 1{(a-1)x_0^{a-1}}. $$ However, in more conventional usage one writes $$ \int_{x_0}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{a+1}} = \frac 1{ax_0^a}, $$ so that the probability that a random variable with this distribution exceeds $x>x_0$ is $(x_0/x)^a,$ and the distribution is $$f(x)\,dx = \dfrac{ax_0^a\,\, dx}{x^{a+1}} \text{ for }x>x_0$$ or $$f(x)\,dx = a\Big( \dfrac{x_0}x \Big)^a \Big( \dfrac{dx} x \Big)\text{ for } x>x_0.$$

Comment: Hi @MichaelHardy, thanks a lot! However you lost me with your last comment. Mathematically, I understand what you did, but I don't know what it's supposed to tell me. Can you elaborate a bit further? Also, because Iosif Pinelis pointed out I should try Cross Validated instead, [I posted the question there as well](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/563921/280304). I feel like your comments are really close to an answer though, so if it's ok with you, I would suggest you post your comments to the other post, but as an answer instead? Then I can delete the question here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you again! I think I have finally understood how it works (see [my answer in the other post}(https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/565651/280304)). I think I should delete this question now, but I also really don't want to remove your helpful comments like that. So again, could you maybe transfer them to the other post?

Comment: I'm glad this helped.